Identify SMD Part Marking AM and MO
I need to know the part number of this IC marked AM. It's probably a sot 70 placed between a master device and slave max7301 ic. My guess is it's a logic gate but I cannot find anything to be sure.
I also have another IC which is also similar with probable marking "MO". Both these ICs have same functionality and I need to know the part numbers.

You might provide board info, and device info from which pulled, if you cannot find a schematic diagram.

The part marked AM is a Nexperia 74AHC1G125GW buffer/line driver.


(source: lcsc.com)

M0 is a Onsemi NL17SZ125 buffer.


(source: lcsc.com)
